# Android Gradle ProguardRelease Failed

Tags: android, gradle

In my project i have n number of dependencies project available. Each project has support-v4-19.1.0.jar file.

When i try to build the application using gradle, ProguardRelease task failed with below error.

```
* What went wrong:
```

Execution failed for task ':CurrenexMobile:proguardRelease'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [build\in
>   termediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar] (Can't read [build\intermediates\exploded-aar\libs\support-v4-19.1.0.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip ent
>   ry [android/support/v4/c/a.class == support-v4-19.1.0.jar:android/support/v4/os/
>   ParcelableCompat.class]))

Can anyone suggest some ideas to solve this ?

Edit :

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
     debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
     release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile(group: 'android', name: 'Lib1', version: '3.7.5', ext: 'aar')
compile(group: 'android', name: 'Lib2', version: '2.0.2', ext: 'aar')
compile(group: 'android', name: 'Lib3', version: '1.2.7', ext: 'aar')
compile(group: 'android', name: 'Lib4', version: '2.2.1', ext: 'aar')
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.+'
}
```

Proguard File

```
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }


# MonkeyTalk Time
-dontwarn com.gorillalogic.**
-keep class com.gorillalogic.** { *; }
-keep interface com.gorillalogic.** { *; }
-keep enum com.gorillalogic.** { *; }

# To skip renaming file and method names
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# EventBus
-keepclassmembers class ** {
 public void onEvent(**);
}

#Skip Logger
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static *** d(...);
public static *** v(...);
public static *** e(...);
}
```

Comment: Can you publish your gradle.build configuration?

Comment: Updated the post with build.gradle file. please check

Comment: You have project libraries Lib1, Lib2, Lib3 and Lib4, rigth? Wich make use of support-v4-19.1.0.jar? Do you have included support-v4-19.1.0.jar on your main project?

Comment: Yes. Lib1,libb2.. all projects having support-v4-19.1.0.jar. My main project doesn't have any support jar file.

Comment: Ok. Please publish your proguard configuration file.

Comment: Updated the post with proguard configuration file

Comment: have you found the solution? I came across the same problem

Comment: @Jerome No solution found.

Answer (score 0):

> Lib1,libb2.. all projects having support-v4-19.1.0.jar

Then that is your problem. Fix those libraries to depend upon the `support-v4` artifact (`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'`) rather than copying the JAR into those projects' `libs/` directories.

Comment: I'm using eclipse. so i can't use gradle commands like compile. I'm using gradle only to generate build and not for development.

Answer (score -1):

Clean and build your project. It worked for me.